# How to set viewcontroller background image on iOS6 in 4 inch screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I need one clarification i have image size 640×1136 it is set view controller background full view this is set fine in iOS 7 because the status bar merge  with view.

```
 self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iOS-7.png"]];
```

[image]

but in iOS 6 i can’t set the size of 640×1136 this image bottom size is hide. how to handle image on view controller background in iOS 6

[image]

How can i resolve the issue

```
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iOS-7.png"]];
   // self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:imageView.image];

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

if i used this above code only worked fine. thanks for answer @Greg but i need to know why screen issues occurs on set self.view backgroundColor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, iOS 7 switched the status bar to be translucent by default, and to allow content views to appear behind it. This is *not* the default for iOS 6. Hence, you're seeing your normal views start just below the status bar, and as you (weren't) scaling the view correctly, it was clipped.

You can get a similar effect for iOS 6 and below. Set the status bar to be translucent:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

and then, for each view controller you have, set:

```
myViewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

This should cause your views to extend below a translucent status bar, similar in style to iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

When you set up the image on imageView set scale mode:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

This should scale your image to fit full size of the view.

//Extended

When you use colorwithpattern... you can create UIImageView with size of your view add image to it with content mode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit and after that call

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[imageView setImage:YOURIMAGE];
`self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:imageView.image];`
```

Comment: i'm  use only self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorwithpattern://];

Comment: see my updated question and you change to UIViewContentModeScaleToFill